# How to access other input attributes in Validator::extend?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, package

As the question title states:
How can you access other input attributes when using Validator::extend?

Upon inspecting Laravel's built-in Validator class, I can see it uses `$this->data` to access other attributes; however you can't directly use `$this`in the closure that Validator::extend requires.

It seems like manually extending the Validator class (through a custom class) is the only option... Am I correct? If so, this seems to me like a serious limitation for converting validators into packages as each package would extend the base Validator class for which PHP would eventually just retains the last defined extension (and thus rendering other validator packages unusable...). Or am I missing something?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I also tried to wrap it up in a package following [this method](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=45312#p45312) by Jason Lewis but I keep getting a `BadMethodCallException` stating that the validation method could not be found... The package is psr-0 compliant and I'm pretty sure it's not a namespacing issue.

Comment: are you able to use `Input::get()` to grab the other field inside your closure?

Comment: I haven't actually thought about fetching input directly through its facade. And surprisingly this **does** work... In case of wrapping it up in a package I'm not quite sure if relying on the facade is the way to go?

Comment: IMO using `Input::get()` is very hacky. What happens when you don't want to validate against data that does not come from a request? Not exactly a reusable custom validation rule..

Comment: definitely 'hacky', I like the answer by @SamV below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After a bit of testing, you can access the array if you use a class and not a callback. As it extends the `Validator` class.

```
class TestRulesValidator extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{

    public function validateTestRule($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        var_dump($this->data);

        exit();
    }

}
```

From the [validation documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules), use:

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
    return new TestRulesValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

Your rule name would be `test_rule`. Remove the `validate` keyword and convert to underscore case.

Just tested this on fresh installation and it works.

**Edit** - You can also use the normal `extend` method and pass an extra parameter.

```
class TestRulesValidator
{

    public function validateTestRule($attribute, $value, $params, $validator) {
        var_dump($validator->getData());
    }

}

Validator::extend('test_rule', 'TestRulesValidator@validateTestRule');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I explored the proposed solution earlier but I stumbled upon a `BadMethodCallException` stating the `validateTestRule` method could not be found...

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation and following the example in there?

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now, but I did notice a little difference between your answer and the one in the docs. You fully qualify the validation method as `Validator::extend('bar', 'FooValidator@validateBar')` whereas the docs just point to the 'validate' prefix `Validator::extend('bar', 'FooValidator@validate')`.

Comment: Update: just tried it but I can't get it to work. I'm getting a `BindingResolutionException` stating `Target [Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface] is not instantiable`.

Comment: I've never tried it in a package, maybe look at some other packages that have rules in them?

Comment: @Propaganistas Finally got around to testing it on fresh codebase, had to use resolver instead! See edited answer.

Comment: I'll mark this as solved because your answer now covers most of the question. But as a follow-up, please take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569911/extend-laravel-validator-multiple-times