# 2 custom validators in Laravel as service providers

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

In my Laravel project I use [unique_with](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator) validator and basically I have textarea that allows me to add bulk categories. I need to validate each row of this textarea because multiple rows into database will be added so I also need to use my custom validator.

In my `app/config/app.php` file I use:

```
'Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider',
'Providers\TextareaNameValidatorServiceProvider',
```

to register this validator and my custom one.

The code I use for validation is:

```
    $data = Input::except('submit');
    $data['parent'] = Input::get('parent') ?: null;


    $names = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($data['name']));

    if (count($names) == 1) {
        $rules['name']
            = '
            required |
            unique_with:categories, parent = par_cat';
    }
    else {
        $rules['name'] = 'textareaname'; // my custom validator
    }


    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules,
        Lang::get('forms.validation'));


    if ($validator->passes()) {
    // ...
```

if I have only one line it works without a problem because it uses `unique_with` validator.

My validator is defined this way:

**Service provider:**

```
<?php

namespace Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TextareaNameValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register(){}

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->validator->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new \Utils\TextareaNameValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }

}
```

**Validator itself**:

```
<?php

namespace Utils;

use Validator;


class TextareaNameValidator extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{
    public function validateTextareaName($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $array = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($value));

        if (count($array) !== count(array_unique($array))) {
            return false;
        }


        foreach ($array as $item) {
            $data['name'] = $item;



            $rules['name']
                = '
                required |
                unique_with:categories, parent = par_cat ';

            $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

            if (!$validator->passes()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

If I run this code and go to `textareaname` validator and deliberately I fill form the way that `unique_with` needs to be run in this validator I get:

> Method [validateUniqueWith] does not exist.

However as I said when `unique_with` validator is run not from `textareaname` validator no error occurs.

If I change the order in my providers from:

```
'Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider',
'Providers\TextareaNameValidatorServiceProvider',
```

to

```
'Providers\TextareaNameValidatorServiceProvider',
'Felixkiss\UniqueWithValidator\UniqueWithValidatorServiceProvider',
```

I get the following error:

> Method [validateTextareaname] does not exist.

So it seems there is a problem with using 2 custom validators.

**Question is** - how to register 2 custom validators in Laravel not having such issue?  Or maybe from some reason it's not possible to run custom validator from another custom validator (but looking at the error when changing order of providers causes similar error it seems that's not the case)?

**EDIT**

As I'm trying to solve this issue I moved my code not to use service provider. So I commented this line in `app/config/app.php`:

```
// 'Providers\TextareaNameValidatorServiceProvider',
```

and in my `app/start/global.php` I added:

```
Validator::extend('TextareaName', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $array = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($value));

    if (count($array) !== count(array_unique($array))) {
        return false;
    }


    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $data['name'] = $item;



        $rules['name']
            = '
                required |
                unique_with:categories, parent = par_cat ';

        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if (!$validator->passes()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

code inside the validator is the same as previous. Now it works without a problem. So the issue is when I use service provider to register my validator. Question is - why?

**EDIT2**

It seems that it happens even if I have my 2 custom validators using service provider (and not using `unique_with`). IF I copy code of my TextAreaName (service provider and validator), rename them properly and add both of them into providers there will be always problem with one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no clear info in manual also but **it's not possible to add multpile validator providers**.  [Reference on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569911/extend-laravel-validator-multiple-times).

It seems that not many people know about it. Even `unique_with` validator  (that I mentioned at the beginning) supports only registering as provider. If we had another vendor validator that would also need to be registered as service provider it would be not possible to do it.

So the final solution to use my `textarea_name` validator is:

Removing from `app/config/app.php` line:

```
// 'Providers\TextareaNameValidatorServiceProvider',
```

Add to `app/start/global.php`:

```
Validator::extend('textarea_name', '\Utils\TextAreaNameValidator@validateTextareaName');
```

and defining my validator this way:

```
<?php

namespace Utils;

use Validator;

class TextareaNameValidator
{
    public function validateTextareaName($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $array = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($value));

        if (count($array) !== count(array_unique($array))) {
            return false;
        }


        foreach ($array as $item) {
            $data['name'] = $item;



            $rules['name']
                = '
                required
                |
                unique_with:categories, parent = par_cat
                 ';

            $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

            if (!$validator->passes()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

(notice it doesn't extend `Validator` class anymore)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the error is:

```
validateTextareaname
```

but your class is

```
validateTextareaName
```

(notice the capital "N" for name).

Try changing

```
$rules['name'] = 'textareaname'; // my custom validator
```

to

```
$rules['name'] = 'textarea_name'; // my custom validator
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I noticed it just before your reply. However it doesn't solve the issue. Now I get `Method [validateTextareaName] does not exist.` with capital `N`

Comment: I've also edited my question and added alternative way of registering validator and it works but I don't know why the service provider version doesn't work