# how to get the value of parameter passed in custom validation rule laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, custom-validators

```
The custom validation rule is :

Validator::extend('greater_than', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    if (isset($parameters[0])) {
        return intval($value) > intval($parameter[0]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

max_occupancy rule would then be:

'max_occupancy' => 'required|integer|max:100|greater_than:base_occupancy'
```

but the "$parameters" array returning is :
 array:1 [▼ 0 => "base_occupancy"]. 
so i am not getting the value of base_occupancy to check "greater_than" condition.

Comment: is base_occupancy a field in your form?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491088/how-to-access-other-input-attributes-in-validatorextend

Comment: class AddRoomRequest extends Request {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:2|max:1000',
            'base_occupancy' => 'required|integer|min:0|max:100',
            'max_occupancy' =>  'required|integer|max:100|greater_than:base_occupancy'
        ];
    }

}

Comment: is that for the form  request?

Comment: yes , i created a request "AddRoomRequest", with some rules and has 2 parametrs , which im am trying to relate ie............           'base_occupancy' => 'required|integer|min:0|max:100',             'max_occupancy' => 'required|integer|max:100|greater_than:base_occupancy'

Answer (score 0):

Use `$validator->getData()`. It will return a key-value array that has the key are form input names and the value are their values.

In your case, fix like this:

```
Validator::extend('greater_than', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $all_form_data = $validator->getData();
    if (isset($all_form_data[$parameters[0]])) {
        return intval($value) > intval($all_form_data[$parameters[0]]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```