# Laravel validation for two column value

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have one table which contains two column field, 1.frame_id 2.extra_frame_id

Now I want to check if this two column contains vice-versa value or not by laravel validation.

Let say frame_id contains id = 1, where extra_frame_id contains = 2,5,7
Now If  I'm adding value frame_id = 5 and extra_frame_id 1,4 then it should fire an error.

Please let me know if it's achievable via laravel validation

Comment: You can make a [custom validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules). These are [able to access other data in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491088/how-to-access-other-input-attributes-in-validatorextend).

Comment: Add more example what should be value and what should be invalid clearly.